# Why doesn't django collectstatic work correctly?

Tags: django

When I make collectstatic, it doesn't work, and create static folder and collect into `D:\static\`.

My settings don't work correctly. Why?

Here are my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    'D:\DjangoProjects\mysite']

STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

Comment: Well, you've set `STATIC_ROOT` to (the unix-style equivalent of) `D:\static\ `, so that's where your files will end up...

Comment: If i change it to '\static\' it will be SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: It should be a unix-style path (forward slashes, no `D:`). However, your files _will end up in `STATIC_ROOT`_, and you configured it to point to `D:\static\ `. If you want your files elsewhere, configure `STATIC_ROOT` to point to a different directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, as in many languages, the backslash is the escape character. If you want a literal backslash, you need to escape it itself:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:\\static\\'
```

or you can use the `r''` notation for a literal string:

```
STATIC_ROOT = r'D:\static\'
```

However, the Django documentation says that you should be using forward slashes, even on Windows. It's not clear whether this also applies to STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT, but it is for STATICFILES_DIRS. In that case, STATIC_ROOT would become:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/static/'
```

The `'D:\DjangoProjects\mysite'` you have written is certainly an error, should be `'D:/DjangoProjects/mysite'`.